# Как сделать, чтобы при тестировании класса методом unittest, ф-ция return возращала след. значение?

Tags: python

## Здравствуйте,необходимо проверить функцию def nomera_dopuska() на работоспособность методом unittest.

## Файл city

```
class User():

    def __init__(self,username):
        self.username=username.title()
        self.your_id=[]

    def imya(self):
        print("Введите номера инструкция для пользователя "+self.username)

    def nomer_id(self,nomer_id):
        self.your_id.append(nomer_id)

    def nomera_dopuska(self):
        print("Для пользователя "+self.username+" разрешен следующий допуск:")
        for i in self.your_id:
            print(i)
            return i
```

## Тест файл

```
import unittest
from city import User

class TestProgramm(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):    
        self.exemplar=User("alex")
        self.a=["221","900","12"]

    def test_user3(self):
        for z in self.a:
            self.exemplar.nomer_id(z)

        for z in self.a:
            func=self.exemplar.nomera_dopuska()
            self.assertEqual(z,func)

unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот небольшой пример:

```
import unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase): # Тут мы тестируем
    def test_one(self): # Пример обычного тестирования
        obj = class_for_example(10).get_sqr() # Создаем объект класса и записываем результат (obj = 100) так как 10**2 = 100
        self.assertTrue(obj == 100) # Проверяем вернет ли нам результат 100

    def test_two(self): # Здесь то что вам нужно
        obj_2 = class_for_example(2).iterator() # Опять таки создаем объект 
        for i in obj_2: # Не забываем что нам вернули генератор
            self.assertTrue(i < 5) # Проверяем

class class_for_example: # Пример простого класса который имеет 2 метода
    def __init__(self, value:int):
        self.value = value

    def get_sqr(self):
        return self.value**2

    def iterator(self) -> iter:
        for i in range(self.value):
            yield i # Возвращаем генератор

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Получаем результат:

```
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Разберем детальнее данную конструкцию:

```
def example() -> iter:
    for i in range(5):
        yield i
```

[yield](https://habrahabr.ru/post/132554/) возвращает нам генератор, т.е мы можем поступить так:

```
count = example().__iter__()
print(count.__next__()) # 0
print(count.__next__()) # 1
print(count.__next__()) # 2
```

Или так:

```
for i in count:
    print(i)
```

Получим:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Да функция yield решила мою проблему. В той книге которую читаю она не упоминается. Спасибо,вам.

Comment: Единственное я не понял в том виде как написано у меня,ф-ция return будет всегда возвращать первое значение в списке?

Comment: @Александр `return` означает что будет возвращено значение, и окончена функция, то есть после первого `return` функция остановилась. Таким образом  ваша функция успевает вернуть 1 значение, и останавливается.

Comment: Если мы запустим "тест" модуль в данном виде,который я написал. Он передаст список self.a=["221","900","12"] модулю city. Потом когда интерпретатор из тест модуля вызывает функцию self.exemplar.nomera_dopuska(), эта фунция должна перебрать все значения в списке self.your_id и каждое вернуть. Но по факту она возвращает всегда первое значение "221". Отличие между ф-циями return и yield, как я понял,то что вторая возвращает лишь генератор,не понимаю почему return в этом случае не работает,a yield работает.

Comment: Я же выше объяснял почему :) Почитайте официальную документацию по `yield` and `return`